# Multiselect Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newbie to jQuery. I had to use multiselect in one of my fields in my jQuery pages.
I selected the data and processed and stored it in database. 
I dont want to go through the jQuery code, as of now. I need the values what I selected in the entry pages needs to be reflected in the edit page. I need to know how to do that.

```
<SELECT id="s1" multiple="multiple" name="PLTF_MAP" class="input-box">
    <%  
       try{
           //getting values and names from database                         
           out.println("<option    value="+ temp.getCode()+ ">"+temp.getDesc()+ "</option>");
       }
       }catch(Exception exe){
           exe.printStackTrace();
       }            
    %>
</SELECT>
```

Screenshot below: Platform is my field, In edit page, I need all those selected fields to be checked.

[image]

Comment: Why do you capitalise tag names?

Comment: Just add the `selected=selected` attribute to each `option` you want marked. This is basic HTML.

Comment: It would help if you posted some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Based on the code you've posted there is a syntax error in your try catch, there is an extra `{`

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with jQuery or JS.

Comment: You should at least try to [crop an image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)).

Answer (score 0):

the val function called from the select will return an array if its a multiple:

```
$('select#s1').val();
```

In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdPQw/1/

you can find two example:

1. the first create a select from the selected value of yuor select.
2. The second select the selected item of the first multiselect in the third multiselect.